# Bought a remanufactured transmission online

Tags: automatic-transmission, acura

Okay I have a 98 Acura CL 3.0 with a automatic transmission, well I went online and found one that they say is remanufactured. So I have this transmission sitting on the pallet in my garage and I need some help , is there any why I can tell or check if the transmission is really remanufactured or even good without tearing apart or having it installed in the car physically it looks nice it's been painted it's been cleaned up but that's just cosmetics so like I said it's sitting on the pallet so what can I do to or is there any way to check manually physically without having it in the vehicle please advice thanks

Comment: Who said that it is remanufactured?  The remanufacturer?  The guy who bought if off the remanufacturer? Why don't you trust them?  Did you check on the company before buying it?

Comment: So , nothing changes ? As a boy in the 50's I worked in a small transmission shop;  people would come in ask for an estimate for trans work. Then they said XYZ would put in a rebuilt trans for less , My boss knew XYZ just bolted in junkyard trans, as is.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to check if it has been rebuilt is to take it to pieces and check that it has new parts in it.

To check if it is good would require some serious power to be put through it which would require it being fitted to a test rig or installed in a vehicle.  The cost of getting it tested may make it best just to fit it to your car and see if it works.  If it hasn't really been rebuilt, then even if it works now, you still don't know how long it will work for.

I presume it will have some plugs fitted where the oil cooler pipes usually connect. You could try removing a plug and see if you can get any fluid out of it.  If some comes out and it is not spotlessly clean, then I suppose that would be bad news.

Why don't you trust that it has been rebuilt?

Comment: The "trust" part of this is key!  When purchasing something that's been labelled "remanufactured" the reputation of the company selling it and standing behind it with warranty is what makes the difference.  It's best to deal with an established company that has a good reputation.